# Using SiteNavigationElement in mega menu

Tags: html, seo, structured-data

Guys i have a couple of unclearities.

Am optimising my website for google and i start to use strured data.

**First question:**

My site have main menu with sub menu and that sub manues have own sub menues etc...
Does all sub menues also need to have declared `itemscope itemtype="http://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement`or just parent need to have?
Check my example below:

```
<ul itemscope itemtype="http://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement">
  <li itemprop="name"><a itemprop="url" href="#">Car Parts</a></li>
  <li itemprop="name">
      <a itemprop="url" href="#">Car Models</a>
       <ul itemscope itemtype="http://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" class="dropdown"> <!-- THIS -->
          <li itemprop="name"><a itemprop="url" href="#">Sub menu</a></li>
       </ul>
  </li>
 
</ul>
```

Or just need like this

```
 <ul itemscope itemtype="http://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement">
      <li itemprop="name"><a itemprop="url" href="#">Car Parts</a></li>
      <li itemprop="name">
          <a itemprop="url" href="#">Car Models</a>
           <ul class="dropdown"> <!-- THIS -->
              <li itemprop="name"><a itemprop="url" href="#">Sub menu</a></li>
           </ul>
      </li>     
    </ul>
```

**Second question**

`<li itemprop="name">` value of `itemprop` is `name`. Does this need to stay with `name` value or i need to change `name` => `Car Models` ?

`<a itemprop="url">` does `url` need to change with my `www.example.com/category` or just leave url?

Thanks

Comment: Google does not support this type https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/search-gallery

Answer (score 0):

```
 <ul itemscope itemtype="http://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement">
      <li itemprop="name"><a itemprop="url" href="#">Car Parts</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Car Models</a>
           <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li class="nav-item" itemprop="name">
                  <a class="dropdown-item nav-link" itemprop="url" href="https://stackoverflow.com">stackoverflow</a>
               </li>
           </ul>
      </li>     
    </ul>
```

Itemprop should be defined on the navigation items and not the dropdown containers. You also do not need to repeat the schema declaration nor do you need to redeclare the itemscope.

Also, itemprop="" is defining what type of property the dom item is defining. So it should stay as "name" and "url".

here is a Mozilla article explaining itemprop: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/itemprop